# How much memory would you need to store every possible phone number?

Tags: memory, byte, storage, bit

say we have a 10 digit phone number (xxx) xxx xxxx.  How much memory would be required to store every possible number if every number can be any digit 0-9.

This is my calculation, but I want to make sure it is correct:

There are 10^9 possible combinations (9 digits, each has 10 possible values).
Each digit can be 0 - 9, which is 10 possible values, so each digit must be 4 bits.
Each number is then 4 bits * 9 digits = 36 bits.

(36 bits * 10^9 combinations) / (8 bits/byte) = 4.5 * 10^9 bytes / 10^6 bytes/GB = 4500 GB.

Is that right?  Thanks! :)

Comment: 9 digits? 3+3+4 = 9?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an exercise in arithmetic, not a question about programming.

Comment: It's not just about arithmetic. The number of permutations is, but how to store them in the smallest amount of memory is related to programming, not just math.

Comment: @hatchet The OP didn't ask how to store them in the smallest amount of memory That's an entirely different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store each phone number as a single integer, rather than saving the digits. Because you have assigned 4 bits to hold values 0-10, you are wasting storage. Also, why are there 9 digits? Shouldn't there be 10?

Take the largest phone number possible: 999 999 9999 (or in your example, 999 999 999), then convert it to base 2, to figure out what the largest number of bits required is.

The results for this conversion are:

```
999 999 999  =     111011100110101100100111111111 base 2 (length 30)
999 999 9999 = 1001010100000010111110001111111111 base 2 (length 34)
```

So all numbers can be stored using 30 or 34 bits each, not 36.

The rest of the calculation you can do yourself!

Comment: You might find it easier to do log2(9999999999)

Comment: And then knowing that there is a max bit length of 34 per phone number, and 10000000000 possible phone numbers, the minimum required memory is (34*10000000000) bits = 42500000000 bytes = 41503906.25 KB = ~40531.16 MB = **~39.58 GB**.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a set of phone numbers, that is, a data structure that either contains or does not contain each phone number, all you really need is 10^10 bits. If the nth bit is 1, the phone number with numeric value n is in the set. Otherwise it isn't. A full gigabyte is more than a billion bytes (about 1.074 x 10^9), so 10^10 bits is about 1.164 GB.

If you need to have more information about the phone numbers than that, of course, more memory will be required.